# show extended index equivalent for MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.7

If you look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html) documentation for show index in version 8.0, it says

> ```sql
> SHOW [EXTENDED] {INDEX | INDEXES | KEYS}
>    {FROM | IN} tbl_name
>    [{FROM | IN} db_name]
>    [WHERE expr]
> ```
>
> The optional EXTENDED keyword causes the output to include information about hidden indexes that MySQL uses internally and are not accessible by users.

Without the optional `EXTENDED` keyword, only the normal index parts are visible, the primary key at the end is not visible (`innodb`). I want to see the extended version in `5.7`. How do I see it?

I tried checking in `information_schema` tables like `TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`, `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` etc. The extended info is also not there.

Comment: I am pretty sure the info is not available before 8.0.

Comment: But it’s safe to assume PK is indeed present ?

Answer (score 0):

> But it’s safe to assume PK is indeed present ?

Yes.  (The following applies only to InnoDB; other engines probably differ.)

- A copy of the PK column(s) is tacked on the end of regular indexes.
- `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` work differently, so this discussion may not apply.
- There has been some chatter about whether the FK columns are *redundantly* added, or only if not present in the declared index.
- The benefit of the PK columns being tacked onto an index is for "covering".  This provides a (perhaps) 2x speedup.  Example:  Given `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, if you also have `INDEX(x)`, then `SELECT id FROM t WHERE x=1` (without *any* other columns mentioned), then the query can be performed in the BTree for the index since it is effectively `(x,id)`.
- `UNIQUE` and non-`UNIQUE` work the same except for the uniqueness constraint.  This constraint applies only to the columns specified.  That is, given `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, if you also have `UNIQUE(uuid)`, then `uuid` is checked for uniqueness, even though the BTree containing that index has `(uuid, id)`.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` index, but it is different because it is clustered with the data.  That is it is in the same BTree and that BTree is ordered according to the PK.
- Hence a "point query" using the PK, is a simple drill-down of the PK+data's BTree.
- But a "point query" using a secondary index needs to first drill down the index's BTree to find the PK, then drill down the PK to find the row.  (Exception:  "Covering index", see above, avoids this second drill-down.)